# Equality between two IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> objects

Tags: c#, ienumerable, sequence, equality

I don't think `SequenceEqual` is working between the two because the "middle" elements (`IEnumerable<int>`) aren't using `SequenceEqual`.

```
oneThingy.SequenceEqual(twoThingy)
```

Short of using `String.Join` on the middle elements, is there a way to get equality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SequenceEqual` tests using `Equals`; to use `SequenceEquals` you'll need to implement it yourself. Try using the `Zip` operator with sequence equals.

```
// example
var first = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => Enumerable.Range(1, i));
var second = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => Enumerable.Range(1, i));

bool nestedSequencesEqual = 
    // test if each sequence index is equal        
    first.Zip(second, (f, s) => f.SequenceEqual(s))
    // ensure all like sequences are equal
    .All(b => b);
// returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for @BleuM937 answer.
As an another approach you can use the [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx) overloads with equality comparer:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> one = new IEnumerable<int>[] { new int[] { 1 }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } };
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> two = new IEnumerable<int>[] { new int[] { 1 }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } };

bool nestedSequencesEqual = one.SequenceEqual(two, new SequencesComparer<int>());

class SequencesComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj) {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your hash implementation is broken. `GetHashCode` should reflect `Equals` implementation. With your code it's possible to to find two collections with same `SequenceEquals` yet different hash code. Shouldnt happen.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me...

```
public class IntList : List<int>, IEquatable<IntList>
{
    public bool Equals(IntList other)
    {
        return this.SequenceEqual(other);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<IntList> list1 = new List<IntList>(2);
    List<IntList> list2 = new List<IntList>(2);

    var list11 = new IntList() {1, 2, 3};
    list1.Add(list11);

    var list21 = new IntList() {1, 2, 3};
    list2.Add(list21);


    var result = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx